# Is there a way to calculate residuals when trying to match a function to an image in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, numerical-analysis

I'm trying to optimize the fit of a mathematically defined function to an image I know contains a similar structure. Is there a well-known way to calculate residuals for the fit of the function to an image?

I am using `scipy.minimize.optimize` to try and fit the curve to the image. My strategy is to measure how well my feature, which is segmented in the matrix `B` below, matches my function `f` by minimizing the mean euclidian distance between `B` and `f`.

I have defined the following function which I pass into `scipy.optimize.minimize`:

```py
# x is a tuple of arguments passed to f
# f is the function I am trying to fit to B, which returns a matrix of 0s and 1s
# B is the image I am trying to fit to, whose voxel values are 0 or 1

from scipy.ndimage.morphology import distance_transform_edt
def objective(x, f, B):
    f_matrix = f(*x)
    f_matrix_edt = distance_transform_edt(f_matrix)
    residuals = B * f_matrix_edt
    return residuals.sum()
```

I expect for the solution to converge to a strong fit, but I am getting fits which are not even contained within the bounds of my matrix. I suspect this is because my strategy for calculating residuals is completely wrong in this context!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use a convex weighting function for calculating the residuals (like a parabola) and perform the euclidian distance transform on a skeletonized version of the original image. My objective was therefore to minimize the sum of squared residuals, which was quite effective in fitting the shape to the image.

```py
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import distance_transform_edt
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
def objective(x, f, B):
    f_matrix = f(*x)
    B_skeleton = skeletonize(B)
    B_edt = distance_transform_edt(B_skeleton)
    residuals = f_matrix * B_edt ** 2
    return residuals.sum()
```

This gave some quite good results!